# JQuery obtener el nombre de la misma variable como String

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes no se si es posible obtener el nombre de una variable en `JQuery`, por ejemplo si tengo una variable `var nombre = "juan"`, entonces en un mensaje `alert` quiero obtener `nombre` como resultado.
**¿Se puede hacer esto posible?**
Si en caso es posible se le agradecería mucho que comparta un código simple como ejemplo.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es posible obtener el nombre de la variable desde JavaScript

Aqui te adjunto el codigo de ejemplo el cual devolvera el nombre **myFirstName** que corresponde al nombre de la variable:

```
<script>
    const myFirstName = 'John';
    NombreVariable = Object.keys({myFirstName})[0];
    alert(NombreVariable);
</script>
```

Ejecucion del codigo:

```js
        const myFirstName = 'John';
        NombreVariable = Object.keys({myFirstName})[0];
        alert(NombreVariable);
```

Comment: Gracias @Alexander Rodriguez por tu ayuda me sirvió de mucho.